# "ImportError: No module named path" showing when running software in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python-2.7, module, path, ubuntu-12.04, importerror

I am running one software in ubuntu 12.04. It requires python. I have python 2.7.3 on ubuntu. When try to run command `./cmdsadit sim -c ./Example/SimExample.py` it shows following

```
jayram@ubuntu:~/sadit$ ./cmdsadit sim -c ./Example/SimExample.py
[warning] socketIO_client is not found. Real-time ability is disabled
--> Use [matplotlib] as plot backend
--> [warning] cannot import sql related function, reading for sql server is not supported
WARNING:util:Cannot find [socketIO_client], real-time ability is disabled.
WARNING:util:Cannot import sql related function, reading for sql server is not supported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fs.py", line 10, in <module>
    from networkx.algorithms.traversal.path import single_source_dijkstra_path, dijkstra_path_length
ImportError: No module named path
jayram@ubuntu:~/sadit$
```

Some initial line screenshot of fy.py file is given below

[image]

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory, your import from path module is incorrect 
It should be

`from networkx.algorithms import single_source_dijkstra_path, dijkstra_path_length`